# I removed my-freeze.com NetAssistant, but now can't access two websites

Tags: spyware

I used "Revo Uninstaller" to uninstall the spyware which left me with a problem using Internet Explorer so then downloaded the free version of "Hijack This" from the website and, not reading the Super User answer correctly, used fix for the general issues it found and saved the log file of the other queries.

NetAssistant is completely gone or appears to have - Malwarebytes Malware remover cannot find anything and most Google searches now seem to work correctly. However in removing it I seem to have made an error and now whenever I search for and try to open or try to directly access two sites which I had tried to access via NetAssistant whilst infected IE8 says they cannot be displayed. One of them is Wikipedia and I use both regularly.

I am not sure at what point this happened I think it may have been after using Revo Uninstaller and the second section where it looks for references to netassistant (in the registry?). Not sure if this is relevant but I can remember deleting some flags or something relating to Internet Explorer but not sure what.

Any suggestions?

Comment: start by clearing your Net Temps , cookies, and flush the DNS cache. do a quick check of the "hosts" file if the others didnt clear it up, then ammend your question if it is still broken

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a rootkit. Google "ComboFix download" and click only on the link from Bleepingcomputer.com. Any other source of CompboFix is bogus. You will have 10 minutes to download ComboFix before the link expires. CompoFix is free, if you are prompted for payment you have the wrong file. Do the following in the order listed:

1. Run ComboFix
2. Uninstall old MalwareBytes and reinstall a new copy and run it
3. Visit Microsoft Download Center and search the term 'malicious'. Look through the returns 
   click on the Malicious Software Removal Tool that fits your system, 32 bit or 64 bit.
4. Visit Ninite.com and download CCleaner registry tool. Beware all 'free' registry tuners
   CCleaner is ok, CleanMyPc from www.registry-cleaner.net is the best $29 you'll 
   ever spend.
5. Open your browser and look for something like 'Options'. Click on this and check
   your search settings. Use only Bing or Google, Dogpile, etc. MyWebSearch is a virus.
6. Also check your browsers proxy server settings. Unless you really need this disable
   proxy server settings.

You should now be clean and free from malware/spyware:)

Comment: Thanks so much for this.Ran ComboFix and it has fixed the problem but it crashed the machine. Rebooted ok. How important is it to do step 4 and install and use CleanMyPc? Have done all the others.

Comment: If this is a Windows machine, you could try installing Windows Defender Offline to a USB flash drive and then boot the probably infected machine with the USB flash drive. Then run a full scan on the system. You can download Defender Offline here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline. The installer will format your flash drive so you might want to create a backup of the data that is on it before installing Windows Defender Offline. I have found rootkits this way that weren't detected by anti-virus and TDSSKiller. See http://goo.gl/xh1ey